# javascript beginner- unable to show message box on screen

Tags: javascript

I am simply trying to show a message box on screen.

This is the HTML for the button that invokes the message box---

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

This is the relevant javascript function code--

```
function myFunction()
{
    alert("Hello World!");
}
```

The javascript function is stored at js/fetchdetails.js (path relative to the HTML file).

I have included the JS file in the HTML file using the following code in the head section--

```
<script src="js/fetchdetails.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are using firefox open firebug, for chrome etc use the inspector and check to see if the javascript file has indeed been included. From the path you have given the html file and the js folder are both in the same directory? yes?

Comment: What browser are you testing in? also try including the type attribute `type="button"`

Comment: Add an alert into the top of fetchdetails.js to make sure that's being loaded.

Comment: @ClydeLobo if he does this then he should also change it to an `input` tag.

Comment: @JonTaylor : I agree. Also I have heard `button` tag has some issues on IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in the code you've posted; the error is somewhere else.

Either your `fetchdetails.js` is not being loaded, or some error in javascript not shown here causes your script to stop executing.

Use your browser's inspection tool to look for any error messages, and to verify that the file has loaded correctly (there's usually a "Net" tab for that).

Comment: you are right- there is one more function within the JS file which has an error in it-- I opened the inspector in Google Chrome- thats how I found the error... thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Name</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fetchdetails.js"> </script>

    </head>

    <body>
<button onclick="myFunction();">Try it</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

In your javascript file

```
function myFunction(){alert("Hello World!");}
```

This works perfect for me

If it doesnt work please provide more details or else try these buttons:

```
<button onclick="javascript:myFunction();">Try it</button>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction();" value="Try me"/>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:myFunction();" value="Try Me"/>
```

Hope this helps